# How to read signed 16bit integers from QFile?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I want to read in 16bit integer sample values from an audio file in Qt.

```
char tempbytes[3]; /// 
int sampleposition;
int sample;

QFile file(sourcepath);

if (! file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return;

sampleposition = 120
file.seek(sampleposition );
file.read(tempbytes, 2);
```

Now I have a char array but I want to cast it to an 16 bit signed integer value. The byte order in the wave file is littleendian.

I already tried:

```
sample = qFromLittleEndian<qint16>((uchar*)tempbytes);
```

This worked for some samples but some were completely misinterpreted with wrong values. I compared with the plot of the time signal in audacity.

Is there a better way?

Comment: The reason you got the wrong values us because the expression `(uchar*)tempbytes` returns the memory address of `tempbytes`. The values your were getting were thus addresses, not audio samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not it's a "better" solution, I find it simpler to use a `QDataStream` in these types of cases.  It specifically has an overload for [reading 16-bit integers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#operator-gt-gt-5).

Here's a very basic example:

```
// Open the file and create our data stream
QFile file("filename");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream in(&file);
in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

// Read a 16-bit sample
qint16 sample;
in >> sample
```

Answer (score 0):

The source file is *not* a text file, so don't treat it as such. The correct way to open it is:

```
if (! file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return;
```